# VBScript Runtime Error '800a000d'

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

In our business, we use a security wizard to control and administer active directory security and also to have an audit trail of changes made.  This is a SQL database with an ASP front end, which also has communication to our Active Directory.

The person who wrote the wizard has since our site to work for another part of the company and I am attempting to get something working which is broken.

A simple overview of the system is:

1. User submits a request to an authoriser, who then accepts or rejects the request for the user in question to be granted access to the folder/resource
2. If the authoriser accepts the request, he then opens up the wizard and authorises it - an email is sent to IT for us to grant the access
3. After we have granted the access we then tick a box in the wizard which emails both the user and the authoriser informing them of the granted access

Part of this system gives the authorisers of the folders/resources to do a check of which users have access to their authorising folders.  This has been working well, until we have changed the naming standard of our folders:

Old naming standard - "BusinessFolderPurpose" e.g. "BakerHumanResources"
New naming standard - "Business - Site - Server Location - Folder Purpose" e.g. "Baker - England - Server123 - Human Resources"

When the users are attempting to use the part of the wizard which shows them who has access they are now reciecing the following error message:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch: 'ubound'
>
> /Saw/list_grp_mem.asp, line 18

I suspect the issue is that the new folder naming convention has hypens in it which is causing a problem - but unforuntaltey I am not able to fix it depsite numerous attempts looking at it and much Googling around.

Line 18 is:

```vb
iRowNumber = ubound(GroupArray,2)
```

The full code for the list_grp_mem.asp page is:

```vb
<!--#include file = "database/database.asp"-->
<%

WriteHTMLHeader("Security Access Wizard")
VarUser = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
VarUser =(Right(VarUser,(len(VarUser)-instr(VarUser,"\")))) 
StrGroupName = Request.Form("SecurityGroup")

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Generate Group Membership Listing From Group Passed via StrGroupName
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
If Not IsEmpty(StrGroupName) Then
    
    GroupArray = QueryADGroup("distinguishedName",strGroupName)
    If IsEmpty(GroupArray) Then
        Response.Write "No Group Found"
        Else
            iRowNumber = ubound(GroupArray,2)
            if iRowNumber = 0 Then
            GroupDN =  GroupArray(0,0)
            
            Set RsGroupName = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
            StrSql = "SELECT Company.Description AS Comp_Desc, SecurityGroups.Description AS Sec_Desc, SecurityGroups.SecurityGroup " & _
                     "FROM Company INNER JOIN SecurityGroups ON Company.Company = SecurityGroups.Company " & _
                     "WHERE SecurityGroups.SecurityGroup = '" & StrGroupName & "'"
            RsGroupName.open StrSql,objConn
            Do While NOT RsGroupName.EOF
                Response.Write "<h2>Group Membership For: " & RsGroupName("Comp_Desc") & " - " & RsGroupName("Sec_Desc") & "</h2>" & vbcrlf
                RsGroupName.MoveNext
            Loop
            RsGroupName.Close
            Else
                Response.Write "No Group Found"
            End If
    End If

    arrGrpMem = QueryADUsers("GroupsMembers",GroupDN)
    If IsEmpty(arrGrpMem) Then
        Response.Write "Error Group Not Found"
    Else
        iRowNumber = ubound(arrGrpMem,2)
        If iRowNumber = 0 Then
            Response.Write "Group Currently Has No Members"
        Else
            Response.Write "<table class=" & chr(34) & "Req" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf
            Response.Write "    <tr>"  & vbcrlf
            Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "ReqHead" & Chr(34) & "> Name  </td>" & vbcrlf
            Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "ReqHead" & Chr(34) & "> E-Mail </td>" & vbcrlf
            Response.Write "    </tr>"  & vbcrlf
            For iCounter = 0 To iRowNumber
                If Not IsNull(arrGrpMem(3,iCounter)) Then
                    If Instr(arrGrpMem(3,iCounter),"ZZ") = 0  Then
                        Response.Write "    <tr>"  & vbcrlf
                        Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "ReqLeft" & Chr(34) & "> " & arrGrpMem(3,iCounter) & " " & arrGrpMem(4,iCounter) & " </td>" & vbcrlf
                        Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "ReqLeft" & Chr(34) & ">(" & arrGrpMem(6,iCounter) & ") </td>" & vbcrlf
                        Response.Write "    </tr>"  & vbcrlf
                    End If
                End If
            Next
                Response.Write "</table>" & vbcrlf
        End If
    End If
End IF

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Generate Option Box For Groups For Which User Is A Designated Authoriser
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
If IsEmpty(StrGroupName) Then   
    Response.Write "<h2> Group Membership Report</h2>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<p><b> Please select the area you require a membership report for</b>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<form action=" & chr(34) & "list_grp_mem.asp" & chr(34) & " method=" & chr(34) & "post" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<select name=" & chr(34) & "SecurityGroup" & Chr(34) & ">"
    Set RsAuthGroups = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        StrSql = "SELECT DISTINCT SecurityGroups.SecurityGroup, SecurityGroups.Description AS Sec_Desc ,Authorisation.NTAccount, Company.Type, Company.Description AS Comp_Desc " & _
        "FROM  Company INNER JOIN SecurityGroups ON Company.Company = SecurityGroups.Company INNER JOIN " & _
        "Authorisation ON SecurityGroups.SecurityGroup = dbo.Authorisation.SecurityGroup " & _
        "WHERE     (Company.Type ='1' AND Authorisation.NTAccount = '" & VarUser & "') AND SecurityGroups.Active = 1"
    RsAuthGroups.open StrSql,objConn
    Do While NOT RsAuthGroups.EOF 'Loop through groups and generate form options.
        Response.Write "        <option value=" & chr(34) &  Replace(RsAuthGroups("SecurityGroup")," ","") & chr(34) & "> " & RsAuthGroups("Comp_Desc") & " - " & RsAuthGroups("Sec_Desc") & " </option>"& vbcrlf
        RsAuthGroups.MoveNext
    Loop
    RsAuthGroups.Close
    Response.Write "</select>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<br/><br/>Once you have selected an area please press <b>" & chr(34) & "Next" & chr(34) & "</b></p>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<input type =" & chr(34) & "submit" & chr(34) & "value =" & chr(34) & " Next " & chr(34) & "/>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "</p>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "</form>" & vbcrlf
End If

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Display Link Back To Homepage
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response.Write "<hr class=" & Chr(34) & "grey" & chr(34) & "/>" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "<p>" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    <a href=" & chr(34) & "default.asp" & chr(34) & "> Back To Security Access Wizard</a></br>" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "</p>" & vbcrlf

%>

<%WriteHTMLFooter()%>
```

***EDIT: Here is a copy & paste of the QueryADGroup from Database.asp:***

```vb
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' QueryADGroup Returns An Array 
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function QueryADGroup(StrQryType,StrQryValue)
    Set oRootDSE        = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    sDomainADsPath      = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Set oRootDSE        = Nothing
    Set oCon            = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sUser               = "removed"
    sPassword           = "removed"
    oCon.Provider       = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open "ADProvider", sUser, sPassword
    Set oCmd            = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    sProperties     = "distinguishedName"
    select case StrQryType
      case "distinguishedName,cn"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case else
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
    end select
    oCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
    If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
    QueryADGroup = Null
    Else
    QueryADGroup = oRecordSet.GetRows() 
    End If
    oRecordSet.Close
    oCon.Close
End Function
```

Is anyone able to help/assist me try and figure out what the issue is please?

I'd be most grateful for any pointers!

**Further error**

```
No Group Found
```

> Provider error '8007203e'
>
> The search filter cannot be recognized.
>
> /Saw/database/database.asp, line 173

After implementing @Lankymart's suggestion

Line 173 is:

```vb
If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
```

This is the section of database.asp where it is trying to get the users from AD:

```vb
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get Users From Query
'
' Returns 2D Array with user infomation in following format
'       0,x - User Principle Name
'       1,x - SAMAccount Name(NTAccount)
'       2,x - Display Name
'       3,x - Given Name
'       4,x - Surname
'       5,x - Description (For Some Reason Its returned as an array)
'       6,x - Email
'       7,x - SID (Binary)
'       9,x - Distinguised Name
'       10,x - Job Title
'       11,x - Company
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function QueryADUsers(StrQryType,StrQryValue)
    
    Set oRootDSE        = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    sDomainADsPath      = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Set oRootDSE        = Nothing
    Set oCon        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sUser               = "removed"
    sPassword           = "removed"
    oCon.Provider       = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open "ADProvider", sUser, sPassword
    Set oCmd        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    sProperties     = "userPrincipalName,SAMAccountname,name,givenName,sn,description,mail,objectsid,memberof,distinguishedName,title,company"
    select case StrQryType
      case "Surname"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(sn=" & StrQryValue & "*));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case "SAMAccountName"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case "GroupsMembers"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(MemberOf= " & StrQryValue & " ));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case else
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(userPrincipalName=" & StrQryValue & "*));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
    end select
    
    oCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
    If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
    QueryADUser = Null
    Else
    'oRecordset.Sort "sn,givenName"
    QueryADUsers = oRecordSet.GetRows() 
    End If
    oRecordSet.Close
    oCon.Close
End Function
```

Comment: You say a SQL database, do you perhaps mean a MS SQL Server database?

Comment: What does `QueryADGroup` return? Has it changed recently or anything that causes it to not return a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @jarlh - Sorry, yes is an MS SQL database

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I'm sorry but I am not a programmer so I am struggling to understand what you are asking.  As far as I'm aware there is nothing that has changed on the coding side, only the security group naming convention.

Comment: @shahkalpesh is on the right track, without the definition of `QueryADGroup()` function how are we supposed to advise? My guess is it should return a 2 Dimensional Array but for whatever reason it doesn't, however I would then expect to check for the array using `IsArray()` instead of `IsEmpty()`. Thing is you maybe doing that in `QueryADGroup()` already and returning `Empty` if no results are returned so it's all pure guess work at this point.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I have now edited with a copy of the QueryADGroup, thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcGee: Now, see if `QueryADGroup = oRecordSet.GetRows() ` line gets called and it returns an array. You can add `response.write("null")` before `QueryADGroup = Null` and `response.write("data found")` before `QueryADGroup = oRecordSet.GetRows()` to see what line gets executed & what is shown in the output. i.e. null or data found.

Comment: I have to point out that using `-` in a file or folder name is a bad convention, especially as it is recognised as a switch character to some executables in command line mode. Personally, I would also frown upon spaces in a file/folder name, but that's the coder in me coming out.

Comment: @Paul It's not a deal breaker but definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: @Paul I actually made a typo, it's our AD security groups which we use to apply permissions to folders that have had the naming convention change and not the folders themselves.

Comment: I would wager that line 173 is actually `Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute` rather then the one posted due to the nature of the error.

Comment: After the `End Select` add `Response.Write "Command = " & oCmd.CommandText` to see how the `CommandText` outputs so you can check it for syntax errors. The error suggests there is an issue with the LDAP query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the Problem?

The problem is the use of `IsEmpty()` as the validation check when you return `GroupArray` from the `QueryADGroup()` function.

This is because `IsEmpty()` is designed to return `True` if either of two conditions are met;

1. Variable has not been initialised *(no value assigned)*.
2. Variable has been explicitly set to `vbEmpty`.

anything else will return `False` even variables assigned to `Null`.

> Snippet from [MSDN - IsEmpty Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa(v=vs.84).aspx)
>
> ***IsEmpty*** returns **True** if the variable is uninitialized, or is explicitly set to Empty; otherwise, it returns **False**. **False** is always returned if expression contains more than one variable.
>   The following example uses the **IsEmpty** function to determine whether a variable has been initialized:
>
> ```vb
> Dim MyVar, MyCheck
> MyCheck = IsEmpty(MyVar)   ' Returns True.
> MyVar = Null               ' Assign Null.
> MyCheck = IsEmpty(MyVar)   ' Returns False.
> MyVar = Empty              ' Assign Empty.
> MyCheck = IsEmpty(MyVar)   ' Returns True.
> ```

#### What Causes the `Type mismatch` Error?

By setting `QueryADGroup = Null` in the `QueryADGroup()` function you are bypassing the `IsEmpty()` check because it will always be `False`. That means when the line

```vb
iRowNumber = ubound(GroupArray,2)
```

attempts to check the upper bounds of `Null` it fails with the error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch: 'ubound'
>
> /Saw/list_grp_mem.asp, line 18

because it expects an `Array` not a `Null`.

#### Suggested Solutions

Instead you can do two things.

1. Change `QueryADGroup = Null` to `QueryADGroup = Empty` that way `IsEmpty()` will return `True` now that `Empty` has been explicitly set.

   ```vb
   QueryADGroup = Empty
   ```
2. Use `IsArray()` instead of `IsEmpty()` to check for a valid return value. As the result is always expected to be an `Array` this seems the better option, as it will catch any return values that are not valid Arrays.

   ```vb
   If Not IsArray(GroupArray) Then
   ```

---

#### Useful Links

- [MSDN - IsArray Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdxy3zda(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Updated: Fixed reference, that should have pointed to `IsArray(GroupArray)`

Comment: thanks very much for this.  I have implemented your suggestion but I now receive a further error "Provider error '8007203e'" - I have updated the post above.  Are you able to help me out with this?