# LDAP Lookup - Provider error '8007203e'

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, ldap

In our company we have a security wizard, for users to request access to folders.  The person who write this has since moved in to another area of the business and I am trying to solve a problem with it.

The system is access by our users via an ASP page.  It uses an LDAP lookup to query Microsoft Active Directory.  The database referenced by the ASP is Microsoft SQL Server.  The problem page is doing an LDAP lookup for user and group details.  This shows a user who is a member of a specific security group.

I previously raised a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33627637/692942) on a different area of this system (which [was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630985/692942)) but now this error has occurred.

The output is:

```
No Group FoundCommand = ;(&(objectCategory=user)(MemberOf= ));userPrincipalName
,SAMAccountname,name,givenName,sn,description,mail,objectsid,memberof
,distinguishedName,title,company
```

*<sup>Wrapped for readabilitty</sup>*

The error is:

> Provider error '8007203e'
>
> The search filter cannot be recognized.
>
> /Saw/database/database.asp, line 175

Here is line 175 from database.asp:

```vb
If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
```

Here is database.asp in it's entirety:

```vb
<%
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Setup Database Connection
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'objConn.Open "DBQ=" &  Server.Mappath("database/folderperm.mdb") & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"    'DSN-Less Access Connection
'objConn.open "DSN=PermissionsRequest;UID=PermReq;PWD=PermReq;DATABASE=SecurityAccessWizard" ' SQL Version
objConn.open "DSN=SecurityAccessWizard;UID=SecurityAccessWizard;PWD=removed;DATABASE=CIT_SecurityAccessWizard" ' SQL Version

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Count Number Of Records In Record Set
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function ResolveAccessType(VarAccessType)
    select case VarAccessType
      case 1
        ResolveAccessType = "Folder Access"
      case 2
        ResolveAccessType = "Applicaiton Access"
      case 3
        ResolveAccessType = "System Access"
      case 4
        ResolveAccessType = "New Accounts"
      case else
        ResolveAccessType = "None"
    end select
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Count Number Of Records In Record Set
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetRecordCount (rs)
    i = 0 
    If Not RS.Eof Then
        RS.MoveFirst
        Do While Not RS.EOF
            i = i + 1
            RS.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    If i > 0 Then
        RS.MoveFirst
    End If
   GetRecordCount = i
End Function
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
' Convert Binary To Decimal As String (Used To Get SID)
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
Function BinaryToDecimalString(Binary)
  Dim I, S
  For I = 1 To LenB(Binary)
    S = S & AscB(MidB(Binary, I, 1))
  Next
  BinaryToDecimalString = S
End Function
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
' Mail Sending Routine
' -------------------------------------------------------------------

Function SendMail(VarTo,VarFrom,VarCC,VarBCC,VarSubject,VarTextBody)

Dim objConfig  ' As CDO.Configuration
Dim objMessage ' As CDO.Message
Dim Fields     ' As ADODB.Fields

' Get a handle on the config object and it's fields
Set objConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Fields = objConfig.Fields

' Set config fields we care about
With Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod)       = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer)            = "telddc1.oa.local"
    .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort)        = 25
    .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 10
    .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate)      = cdoAnonymous
    .Update
End With

Set objMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig

With objMessage
    .To       = VarTo
    .From     = VarFrom
    .CC       = VarCc
    .BCC      = VarBcc
    .Subject  = VarSubject
    .TextBody = VarTextBody
    .Send
End With

Set Fields = Nothing
Set objMessage = Nothing
Set objConfig = Nothing

End Function 

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' QueryADGroup Returns An Array 
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function QueryADGroup(StrQryType,StrQryValue)
    Set oRootDSE        = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    sDomainADsPath      = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Set oRootDSE        = Nothing
    Set oCon            = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sUser               = "removed"
    sPassword           = "removed"
    oCon.Provider       = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open "ADProvider", sUser, sPassword
    Set oCmd            = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    sProperties     = "distinguishedName"
    select case StrQryType
      case "distinguishedName,cn"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case else
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
    end select
    oCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
    If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
    QueryADGroup = Null
    Else
    QueryADGroup = oRecordSet.GetRows() 
    End If
    oRecordSet.Close
    oCon.Close
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get Users From Query
'
' Returns 2D Array with user infomation in following format
'       0,x - User Principle Name
'       1,x - SAMAccount Name(NTAccount)
'       2,x - Display Name
'       3,x - Given Name
'       4,x - Surname
'       5,x - Description (For Some Reason Its returned as an array)
'       6,x - Email
'       7,x - SID (Binary)
'       9,x - Distinguised Name
'       10,x - Job Title
'       11,x - Company
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function QueryADUsers(StrQryType,StrQryValue)

    Set oRootDSE        = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    sDomainADsPath      = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Set oRootDSE        = Nothing
    Set oCon        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sUser               = "removed"
    sPassword           = "removed"
    oCon.Provider       = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open "ADProvider", sUser, sPassword
    Set oCmd        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    sProperties     = "userPrincipalName,SAMAccountname,name,givenName,sn,description,mail,objectsid,memberof,distinguishedName,title,company"
    select case StrQryType
      case "Surname"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(sn=" & StrQryValue & "*));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case "SAMAccountName"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" & StrQryValue & "));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case "GroupsMembers"
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(MemberOf= " & StrQryValue & " ));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
      case else
        oCmd.CommandText    = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(userPrincipalName=" & StrQryValue & "*));" & sProperties '& ";subtree"
    end select

    Response.Write "Command = " & oCmd.CommandText

    oCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
    If oRecordSet.BOF = True Then
    QueryADUser = Null
    Else
    'oRecordset.Sort "sn,givenName"
    QueryADUsers = oRecordSet.GetRows() 
    End If
    oRecordSet.Close
    oCon.Close
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get User Information From UserPrincipleName(NTUsername)
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Function GetADUserDetails(StrQryName,VarGivenName,VarSurname,VarEmail,VarSID)

    UsersArray = QueryADUsers("SAMAccountName",StrQryName)
    If IsEmpty(UsersArray) Then
        VarName         = "Unknown User"
        VarGivenName    = "Unknown"
        VarSurname      = "User"
        VarEMail        = "Please Contact Central IT"
        GetADUserDetails = 0
    Else
        iRowNumber = ubound(UsersArray,2)
        if iRowNumber = 0 Then
            VarName             = UsersArray(1,iRowNumber)
            VarGivenName        = UsersArray(3,iRowNumber)
            VarSurname          = UsersArray(4,iRowNumber)
            VarEMail            = StrQryName + "@domain.com"
            'VarSID             = BinaryToDecimalString(UsersArray(7,iRowNumber))
            VarSID              = HexStrToDecStr(OctetToHexStr(UsersArray(7,iRowNumber)))
            'VarSID             = SecurityIdentifier(entry.Properties("objectSid").Value, 0).ToString()
            GetADUserDetails    = 1
        Else
            VarName             = "Unknown User"
            VarGivenName        = "Unknown"
            VarSurname          = "User"
            VarEMail            = "Please Contact Central IT"
            GetADUserDetails    = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get Groups SAMAccountName is a member of
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function GetADUserGroupMembership(StrSAMAccountName)
    GroupArray = QueryADUsers("SAMAccountName",StrSAMAccountName)
    If IsEmpty(GroupArray) Then
        GetADUserGroupMembership = 0
    Else
        iRowNumber = ubound(GroupArray,2)
        if iRowNumber = 0 Then
            GetADUserGroupMembership = GroupArray(8,iRowNumber)
        Else
            GetADUserGroupMembership = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Return If User Is A Member Of Specified Group
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function IsMemberOfGroup(strSAMAccountName,StrGroup)
    VarGroupMembership = GetADUserGroupMembership(strSAMAccountName)
    If IsNull(VarGroupMembership) Then
        IsMemberOfGroup = False 
    Else
        If Ubound(Filter(VarGroupMembership,StrGroup,1)) = 0 Then
            IsMemberOfGroup = True
        Else
            IsMemberOfGroup = False
        End If
    End If
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get User Information From UserPrincipleName(NTUsername)
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function GetNameFromNTUser(StrNTUser)

If GetADUserDetails(StrNTUser,VarGivenName,VarSurname,VarEmail,VarSID)  = 0 Then
    GetNameFromNTUser = "No User Found"
Else
    GetNameFromNTUser = VarGivenName & " " & VarSurname
End If

End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' QuickSort
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub QuickSort(vec,loBound,hiBound)
  Dim pivot,loSwap,hiSwap,temp

  '== This procedure is adapted from the algorithm given in:
  '==    Data Abstractions & Structures using C++ by
  '==    Mark Headington and David Riley, pg. 586
  '== Quicksort is the fastest array sorting routine for
  '== unordered arrays.  Its big O is  n log n


  '== Two items to sort
  if hiBound - loBound = 1 then
    if vec(loBound) > vec(hiBound) then
      temp=vec(loBound)
      vec(loBound) = vec(hiBound)
      vec(hiBound) = temp
    End If
  End If

  '== Three or more items to sort
  pivot = vec(int((loBound + hiBound) / 2))
  vec(int((loBound + hiBound) / 2)) = vec(loBound)
  vec(loBound) = pivot
  loSwap = loBound + 1
  hiSwap = hiBound

  do
    '== Find the right loSwap
    while loSwap < hiSwap and vec(loSwap) <= pivot
      loSwap = loSwap + 1
    wend
    '== Find the right hiSwap
    while vec(hiSwap) > pivot
      hiSwap = hiSwap - 1
    wend
    '== Swap values if loSwap is less then hiSwap
    if loSwap < hiSwap then
      temp = vec(loSwap)
      vec(loSwap) = vec(hiSwap)
      vec(hiSwap) = temp
    End If
  loop while loSwap < hiSwap

  vec(loBound) = vec(hiSwap)
  vec(hiSwap) = pivot

  '== Recursively call function .. the beauty of Quicksort
    '== 2 or more items in first section
    if loBound < (hiSwap - 1) then Call QuickSort(vec,loBound,hiSwap-1)
    '== 2 or more items in second section
    if hiSwap + 1 < hibound then Call QuickSort(vec,hiSwap+1,hiBound)

End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Strip out reserved Characters
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function StripSpecialChar(inFileName)
     arrSpecialChar  = Array("%20","%","#","+","(",")","&","$","@","!","*","<",">","?","/","|","\",",","-","'",":")
     strorigFileName = inFileName
     intCounter = 0
     intSpecialCharArrayNum = Ubound(arrSpecialChar) + 1
     Do Until intCounter =   intSpecialCharArrayNum
      sOut = replace(strorigFileName,arrSpecialChar(intCounter)  ,"")
      intCounter = intCounter + 1
      strorigFileName = sOut
     Loop
    StripSpecialChar = strorigFileName
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Write HTML Header
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function WriteHTMLHeader(VarTitle)
    Response.Write "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " & chr(34) & "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<html>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "    <head>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <meta http-equiv=" & chr(34) & "Content-Type" & chr(34) & " content=" & chr(34) & "text/html; charset=windows-1252" & chr(34) & "/>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <link rel=" & chr(34) & "stylesheet" & chr(34) & " type=" & chr(34) & "text/css" & chr(34) & " href=" & chr(34) & "style.css" & chr(34) & " title=" & chr(34) & "default" & chr(34) & "/>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <title>" & VarTitle & "</title>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "    </head>" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<body>" & vbcrlf

    Response.Write "<table class=" & chr(34) & "head" & chr(34) & "style=" & chr(34) & "width:100% ; height:50px" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "    <tr>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "        <td style=" & chr(34) & "text-align: left; width: 180px; height:40px" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "            <img style=" & chr(34) & "border: 0px solid ; width: 152px; height: 34px;" & chr(34) & " src=" & chr(34) & "graphics/white_yell.gif" & chr(34) & " alt=" & chr(34) & "Logo" & chr(34) & " />" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "        </td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "        <td style=" & chr(34) & "height:50px" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "            <h2 class=" & chr(34) & "head" & chr(34)& ">Company</h2>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "            <h2 class=" & chr(34) & "head" & chr(34)& ">Security Access Wizard</h2>" & vbcrlf   
    Response.Write "        </td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "        <td style=" & chr(34) & "height:50px" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "            <h1 class=" & chr(34) & "head" & chr(34) & ">Security Access Wizard</h1>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "        </td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "    </tr>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "    <tr>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "        <td></td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "        <td></td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "        <td></td>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "    </tr>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "</table>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<table class=" & chr(34) & "head" & chr(34) & "style=" & chr(34) & "width: 100%;" & chr(34) & " cellpadding=" & chr(34) & "0" & chr(34) & " cellspacing=" & chr(34) & "0" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "    <tr>" & vbcrlf  
    Response.Write "        <td style=" & chr(34) & "width: 100%" & chr(34) & "><img style=" & chr(34) & "border: 0px solid ; width: 100%; height: 15px;" & chr(34) & " src=" & chr(34) & "graphics/masthead_top.jpg" & chr(34) & " alt=" & chr(34) & "Header Background" & chr(34) & " /></td>" & vbcrlf   
    Response.Write "    </tr>" & vbcrlf 
    Response.Write "</table>" & vbcrlf  
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Write HTML Footer
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function WriteHTMLFooter()

    Response.Write "<div><hr/></div>"
    Response.Write vbcrlf
    Response.Write "<table class=" & chr(34) & "foot" & chr(34) & " style=" & chr(34) & "width: 100%" & chr(34) & " >" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "    <tr>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <td></td>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "lm" & chr(34) & " ></td>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "cm" & chr(34) & " style=" & chr(34) & "width: 80px" & chr(34) & "><a href=" & chr(34) & "http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" & chr(34) & " title=" & chr(34) & "Valid XHTML 1.1!" & chr(34) & "><img style=" & chr(34) & "border: 0px solid ; width: 80px; height: 15px;" & chr(34) & " src=" & chr(34) & "graphics/validxhtml11.gif" & chr(34) & " alt=" & chr(34) & "Valid XHTML 1.1" & chr(34) & " /></a></td>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "        <td class=" & chr(34) & "cm" & chr(34) & " style=" & chr(34) & "width: 80px" & chr(34) & "><a href=" & chr(34) & "http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" & chr(34) & " title=" & chr(34) & "Valid CSS!" & chr(34) & "><img src=" & chr(34) & "graphics/css.png" & chr(34) & " alt=" & chr(34) & "Valid CSS" & chr(34) & " height=" & chr(34) & "15" & chr(34) & " width=" & chr(34) & "80" & chr(34) & " /></a></td>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "    </tr>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "</table>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "</body>" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write "</html>" & vbcrlf

End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Function to convert OctetString (byte array) to Hex string.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Function OctetToHexStr(arrbytOctet)
    Dim k
    OctetToHexStr = ""
    For k = 1 To Lenb(arrbytOctet)
        OctetToHexStr = OctetToHexStr & Right("0" & Hex(Ascb(Midb(arrbytOctet, k,1))), 2)
    Next
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' ' Function to convert Hex string Sid to Decimal string (SDDL) Sid.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function HexStrToDecStr(strSid)
    ' SID anatomy:
    ' Byte Position
    ' 0   : SID Structure Revision Level (SRL)
    ' 1   : Number of Subauthority/Relative Identifier
    ' 2-7 : Identifier Authority Value (IAV) [48 bits]
    ' 8-x : Variable number of Subauthority or Relative Identifier (RID) [32 bits]
    '
    ' Example:
    '
    '   <Domain/Machine>\Administrator
    ' Pos  :    0 |  1 |  2  3  4  5  6  7 |  8  9 10 11 | 12 13 14 15 | 16 17 18 19 | 20 21 22 23 | 24 25 26 27
    ' Value:   01 | 05 | 00 00 00 00 00 05 | 15 00 00 00 | 06 4E 7D 7F | 11 57 56 7A | 04 11 C5 20 | F4 01 00 00
    ' str  : S- 1 |    |                -5 | -21         | -2138918406 | -2052478737 | -549785860  | -500

    Const BYTES_IN_32BITS = 4
    Const SRL_BYTE = 0
    Const IAV_START_BYTE = 2
    Const IAV_END_BYTE = 7
    Const RID_START_BYTE = 8
    Const MSB = 3 'Most significant byte
    Const LSB = 0 'Least significant byte

    Dim arrbytSid, lngTemp, base, offset, i

    ReDim arrbytSid(Len(strSid)/2 - 1)

    ' Convert hex string into integer array
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrbytSid)
        arrbytSid(i) = CInt("&H" & Mid(strSid, 2 * i + 1, 2))
    Next

    ' Add SRL number
    HexStrToDecStr = "S-" & arrbytSid(SRL_BYTE)

    ' Add Identifier Authority Value
    lngTemp = 0
    For i = IAV_START_BYTE To IAV_END_BYTE
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSid(i)
    Next
    HexStrToDecStr = HexStrToDecStr & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)

    ' Add a variable number of 32-bit subauthority or relative identifier (RID) values.
    ' Bytes are in reverse significant order.
    ' i.e. HEX 01 02 03 04 => HEX 04 03 02 01
    ' = (((0 * 256 + 04) * 256 + 03) * 256 + 02) * 256 + 01
    ' = DEC 67305985
    For base = RID_START_BYTE To UBound(arrbytSid) Step BYTES_IN_32BITS
        lngTemp = 0
        For offset = MSB to LSB Step -1
            lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSid(base + offset)
        Next
        HexStrToDecStr = HexStrToDecStr & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
    Next
End Function ' HexStrToDecStr

%>
```

If anyone is able to provide any help on this I'd be most grateful.

***EDIT:***

I have found some further information.  The error occurs when encountering a security group with our new naming convention.  The old naming convention works fine:

Old:

```
BakerHumanResources
```

New:

```
Baker-HumanResources (Global)
```

I believe this is having a problem with the security group names that have text within brackets at the end (this is a company wide naming convention, I am unable just to change the security group)!

Rather than me blindly trying things in the database.asp, can anyone shed any light on how I can modify it to read these groups?

Thanks.

Comment: As [I said on the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627637/vbscript-runtime-error-800a000d/33630985?noredirect=1#comment55067220_33627637) line 175 is actually more likely to be `Set oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute` rather then the one posted due to the nature of the error.

Comment: @Lankymart - Thanks, I have found some further info out via testing and edited the post above - looks like the database.asp doesn't like security groups with text inside brackets.

Comment: Haven't done much with LDAP for a while it's likely that `-` needs escaping but off hand don't how you do that in LDAP queries.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the edit is `(Global)` part of the new name?

Comment: Yes it is part of the new AD security group name.  I have found any group with a word contained in brackets returns this error.

Comment: You need to escape the brackets with a "\" something like `Baker-HumanResources \(Global\)`.

Comment: @Lankymart - Yes I have Googled and found this, but I am still unaware of which part of the database.asp to change?

Comment: Actually judging by the output don't think the brackets are the problem, from what I can gather the group name is not getting outputted `(MemberOf= )` part of the LDAP query from the output in  the question. Because `MemberOf` is missing a value it's not a valid search filter hence the error.